# Как разрабатываются сайты?

Tags: php, проектирование, mvc

Добрый вечер! Я начинающий веб-разработчик (быдлокодер, если кому удобнее). Несколько дней назад я начал писать простейшую CRM-систему, ничего сверхъестественного - добавление, удаление, редактирование задач, удобный вывод, сортировка и еще несколько тривиальных фич, которые смог придумать. Дело в том, что после написание пары сотен строк кода, я понял, что моя "система" превратилась в обыкновенный, не логичный, сброд файлов, которые подключаются один к другому по принципу "чтобы работало". Прочитав немного про MVC я понял, что тут нужно достаточно углубленное знание PHP конкретно, и ООП в частности. Вопрос заключается вот в чем: не могли бы Вы мне посоветовать какую-то литературу, статьи, либо просто советы от себя, про правильную разработку веб-сайтов, корректное разделение кода, может быть, проектирование, не знаю как правильно выразится, или что-то типа "MVC для начинающих", но где не нужно знание ООП, чтобы я сразу встал, так сказать, на путь истинный.

Comment: так может вам про ООП  лучше почитать ?

Comment: ООП всегда и везде нужен!

Comment: А зачем мне читать про ООП, если я без ООП простейшее спроектировать не могу?

Comment: Ну да для быдлосайта пайдет)

Comment: @bemulima, неправда, не всегда и везде.

Comment: быдлокодер, если кому удобнее

Наоборот, быдлокодер - тупица, который не признает этого. Вы же - новичок, причём разумный. Правда, зря php учите, но...

Comment: Все [многие] ненавидят [недолюбливают] PHP, потому что в нем вот такая ситуация, когда проект превратился в помойку, встречается слишком часто. Так что для начала нужно попробовать что-то, что будет поддреживать жесткую структуру вашего проекта. Вот тут про django писали, он как раз подходит, сделать на нем помойку из файлов на порядок сложнее, так как в документации четко написано, где какой код должен жить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Котеров, Костарев, «PHP 5»**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2172211/). Изучайте, тут есть серьёзные разделы по проектированию веб-приложений.

Comment: Спасибо. На самом деле я прочитал половину этой книги, как раз дошел до ООП, но не стал читать дальше, так как решил закрепить как следует то, что уже изучил. Видать, последний раздел книги "Приемы программирование на PHP5", глава "Код и шаблоны страницы", это как раз то, что мне будет полезно. Буду рад еще каким-то советам.

Answer (score 0):

/me советует Django как того самого представителя MVC,достаточно интерсная и удобная штукенция.Сам на ней пишу сайт сейчас,ибо с пыхапе вязаться убежденно не хочу.Есть модуль новостей,каталог товаров,обратная связь,поиск по файлам(это то что реализовано мной с помощью руководств).Плюсом есть возможносте обсуждений,коментариев...Короче-рекомендую.Если заинтересуешься и начнешь ковыряться-покажу исходники своего сайта(не такая уж это и тайна))).Плюсом джанго написан на питоне у которого более читабельный синтаксис чем у пыхапе.

Comment: Django — это MVT. Да, различие тонкое, но оно есть.

Answer (score 0):

> быдлокодер, если кому удобнее

+1 уважаю разумную самокритику)

---

по делу, предложу взглянуть на фреймворк [Laravel](http://laravel.ru/) который мне так полюбился! Все понятно и просто, есть сайт с русской документацией(туда дана ссылка). Там конечно ООП, ведь MVC без ООП невозможна в принципе, но сам фреймворк на столько легок и понятен, что через месяц другой, вы уже представить себе не сможете написание адекватного кода без пространства имен - не то что просто ООП!

Comment: @Palmervan [ткните сюда, узнаете много нового, про MVC без ООП](http://www.chicagoboss.org/index.htm) :P

Comment: @eicto, в эрланге ООП со своей атмосферой )

Comment: ну как-то не заметил я там ООП :) я вообще про что MVC и ООП - понятия слабо связанные.

Comment: нарыл пока пытался выяснить считает кто-нибудь всерьёз erlang OOP http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/